# Liferay 6.2 CE ga2 - AlloyUI breaks the portal. Any suggestions?

Tags: liferay, portlet

How to use AlloyUI 3.0.1 within a portlet in Liferay 6.2 The version without losing functionality in the rest of the portal.

happens whether or not I import the following

```
<script src="http://cdn.alloyui.com/3.0.1/aui/aui-min.js"></script>
<link href="http://cdn.alloyui.com/3.0.1/aui-css/css/bootstrap.min.css" rel="stylesheet"></link>
```

this is my code...

liferay-portlet.xml

```
<?xml version="1.0"?>
<!DOCTYPE liferay-portlet-app PUBLIC "-//Liferay//DTD Portlet Application 6.2.0//EN" "http://www.liferay.com/dtd/liferay-portlet-app_6_2_0.dtd">

<liferay-portlet-app>
    <portlet>
        <portlet-name>example-input-alert</portlet-name>
        <icon>/icon.png</icon>
        <header-portlet-css>/css/main.css</header-portlet-css>
        <header-portlet-css>http://cdn.alloyui.com/3.0.1/aui-css/css/bootstrap.min.css</header-portlet-css>
        <header-portlet-javascript>http://cdn.alloyui.com/3.0.1/aui/aui-min.js</header-portlet-javascript>
        <footer-portlet-javascript>/js/main.js</footer-portlet-javascript>
        <css-class-wrapper>example-input-alert-portlet</css-class-wrapper>
    </portlet>
    <role-mapper>
        <role-name>administrator</role-name>
        <role-link>Administrator</role-link>
    </role-mapper>
    <role-mapper>
        <role-name>guest</role-name>
        <role-link>Guest</role-link>
    </role-mapper>
    <role-mapper>
        <role-name>power-user</role-name>
        <role-link>Power User</role-link>
    </role-mapper>
    <role-mapper>
        <role-name>user</role-name>
        <role-link>User</role-link>
    </role-mapper>
</liferay-portlet-app>


Resource "http://cdn.alloyui.com/3.0.1/aui/aui-min.js" not found.
```

view.jsp

```
<%@ taglib uri="http://java.sun.com/portlet_2_0" prefix="portlet"%>

<portlet:defineObjects />


<div id="myAlert"></div>

<script>
    YUI()
            .use(
                    'aui-alert',
                    function(Y) {
                        new Y.Alert(
                                {
                                    animated : true,
                                    bodyContent : 'Thank You Mario! But Our Princess Is In That Castle!',
                                    boundingBox : '#myAlert',
                                    closeable : true,
                                    cssClass : 'alert-warning',
                                    destroyOnHide : false,
                                    duration : 1,
                                    render : true
                                });
                    });
</script>
```

before
[image]

after
[image]

some elements disappear portal and portlets lose other functionality...

thx !

Comment: Have you tried importing the library using liferay-portlet.xml?

Comment: yes Geditdk...add the headboards and did not work. also try downloading the libraries directly into css and js directories and does not work...

Comment: Do you have your Portlet source online, I can take a look?

Comment: I'm sorry , I'm working offline testing to move to production. but what I have is simple. I'm trying to replicate this example http://alloyui.com/examples/alert/real-world/ and I 've had no luck. tnk

Answer (score 1):

This is the response of staff Liferay...

[image]

Comment: It does state in the documentation that you can only include new version, I would have thought there was a way to do it (using no conflict mode?) But I guess not.

Answer (score 0):

You need to import the library using `liferay-portlet.xml` in your portlet:

```
<header-portlet-css>http://cdn.alloyui.com/3.0.1/aui-css/css/bootstrap.min.css</header-portlet-css>
<header-portlet-javascript>http://cdn.alloyui.com/3.0.1/aui/aui-min.js</header-portlet-javascript>
```

[See the docs](https://www.liferay.com/documentation/liferay-portal/6.0/development/-/ai/anatomy-of-a-portlet) (It's explained at the bottom)

Comment: Does not work for me. the second link is not recognized and continues to break the functionality of the portal.